# Sending Multiple points to the google map

Tags: android

You had asked a question about sending multiple points to the google map. So is it possible to send multiple points to the google map? If Yes then kindly tell me the solution

Comment: What do you mean in "sending" ? Do you mean to set multiple markers on Google Map?

Comment: Nguyễn Hoài Nam, Yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using waypoints parameter in google direction api request

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=30.0519741,31.3384344&destination=30.0508504,31.341181&waypoints=optimize:true|30.0512683,31.3339927|30.05515,31.3427045&sensor=false
```

but please note that you can't send more than 8 waypoints unless you are a premium user not a free one

please refer to the below link for more details

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/